# Ruby test for "\0" null?

Tags: ruby, null, string

I have some odd characters showing up in strings that are breaking a script. From what I can tell by `put badstring` to console they are `"\0\0\0\0"`.

I'd like to test for this so I can ignore them...but how?

thought that's what `blank?` and `empty?` were for?!? :

```
> badstring = "\0"
 => "\u0000" 
> badstring.blank?
NoMethodError: undefined method `blank?' for "\u0000":String
    from (irb):97
    from /Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
> badstring.empty?
 => false
> badstring.nil?
 => false
```

Edit: Trying to recreate this in irb but having trouble:

```
> test1 = "\0\0\0\0"
 => "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000" 
> test2 = '\0\0\0\0'
 => "\\0\\0\\0\\0"
```

what I want is a `"\0\0\0\0"` string so I can find a way to test `if mystring == "\0\0\0\0"` or something of the sort.

Comment: Maybe your string isn't ASCII like you are assuming, and actually is something like UTF-16 or UTF-32, which we'd expect to have multiple zero-bytes. I'd recommend ruling out that possibility first, and maybe let Ruby convert the strings, before you try a hatchet job and chop up the string, possibly making other characters indecipherable.

Comment: what are the strings you are going to classified as bad string? accordingly we will think.

Comment: Is there a better way to identify what kind of "string" it is? Might even be some null character(s)? All I know is `puts` returns `"\0\0\0\0"`

Comment: Where are you *getting* the string? A file? A web page? Is the file only four bytes long?

Comment: It's the creator code from **Mac OS (Classic)** files. I need to convert thousands of ancient (~1980s) files into a more modern format. Using `GetFileInfo -c <filename>` on Mac OS X to get the 4 byte creator code out of the filesystem. Typically I get an alpha-numeric response but some files are returning `\0\0\0\0` whatever that is?!?

Comment: `"\0"` represents the unprintable NUL character which consists of only zero bits. Probably the format you are parsing uses this to denote an empty string.

Comment: See my **edit** above. How can I test for this string?

Answer (score 4):

You could just remove `"\0"` chars with

```
badstring.delete!("\0")
```

Full example

```
badstring = "\0"
badstring.delete!("\0")
badstring.empty?
#=> true
```

Use `delete` instead of `delete!` if you want to keep the original string around.

Answer (score 4):

First of all `blank?` is a Rails helper. Try this instead:

```
badstring =~ /\x00/
```

if this returns an integer then the given string includes `"\0"`, if this returns `nil` then   the given string does not include `"\0"`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like we need to verify the encoding and characters here. You can check the string's encoding type with `"string".encoding`. Then you can see which character codes are actually being used here with `badstring.chars.map(&:ord)`. Then you can replace / remove the characters using `character_code.chr(encoding)`.